# softmax activation function interpretation

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, softmax

I have a neural network in tensorflow that that has three hidden layers and the output layer has two neurons and it is represented by a one hot encoded value (possible output 0 or 1 so [1, 0] and [0, 1]).
The input layer is formed by 60 neurons, the activations within the hidden layers is reLU, I use AdamOptimizer with a learning rate of 0.001.
I have a problem when I try to compute the result of the network model:

## prediction - the variable that represents the network's output

```
prediction_run = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: mydata.reshape(1, 60)})
print("Original class: ", [1, 0], "Predicted values: ", prediction_run)
```

This will output this: 
Original class:  [ 1.  0.] Predicted values:  [[  1.00000000e+00   3.35827508e-08]]

Since I`m using the softmax in the final layer, isn't this supposed to be an output that will sum up to 1? Like a probability or something. I`m not able to understand those predicted numbers since the softmax is supposed to transform them but they are not.

```
self.tf.nn.softmax(self.tf.matmul(last_hidden_layer_activation, `output_layer_weights) + output_layer_biases)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. `Softmax` output is supposed to sum to 1.

The issue is that of the **floating point numbers**. There is no such thing as absolute zero in case of floating point numbers. There is always a bit of uncertainity in floating point. More information [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/)